# Required switches button instead of checkboxes

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have used Angular2, Gulp and Bootstrap3 in my project. Can anyone help me to implement switches instead of checkboxes in my html page?
I found one solution on the site https://github.com/yuyang041060120/angular2-ui-switch

But instead of downloading via:

```
npm install angular2-switches-ui --save
```

Can i add it to my package.json so that target system where my application hosted i.e. server, i need not to run that command.

My main.ts files is as:

```
import { UiSwitchModule } from 'angular2-ui-switch';
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@router-depricated'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap (AppComponent,[
  UiSwitchModule,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS
    ]);
  })
  export class AppModule {
}
```

So ran the command

```
npm install angular2-switches-ui --save
```

But it is showing me that error
Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading node_modules/angular2-ui-switch.js

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: i just want to have iphone like switches instead of checkbox. i followed this link https://github.com/yuyang041060120/angular2-ui-switch but it is throwing me an error as 
or: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:5555/node_modules/angular2-ui-switch.js

Comment: That's fine of course. Uh, and please add the code ;-)

Comment: i have aaded my main.ts file.. This is the only file where i have made changes w.r.t the switches button

Comment: right now my application is on angular2 RC-6 version

Comment: `bootstrap()` is obsolete since a few months. Use `NgModule` https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html. It's unlikely `UiSwitcherModule` will work with your RC-6 version.

Comment: I hope you see now why I requested code. Your question didn't contain the most essential parts necessary to provide support for your problem but a few lines of code made it immediately obvious.

Comment: yes, you're right.. Do we have any other way to acheive this for angular2 RC6

Comment: You can check if there is an older version of this `angular2-switches-ui` library that is compatible with your Angular2 version. But it should be quite easy to upgrade to the newest Angular2 version from RC.6, therefor I think this is what you should do. Lots of bugs were fixed since then.